# Continuity assumptions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am reading a text where I frequently find assumptions of the form $f$ piecewise continuous with piecewise continuous derivative on an interval $[a,b]$. I wonder if this assumption makes sense, in light of the fact that piecewise continuity implies the only discontinuities allowed are of finite type - jumps basically - but if $f$ has a jump at $a$, $f'$ behaves has an "infinite jump" at that point, so that it cannot even be piecewise continuous.

Comment: Even if $f$ is continuous, $f'$ could be discontinuous.

Comment: That's 100% true, but what I mean is rather that if $f$ is not continuous, then $f'$ surely is not, and in a "worse" way.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your question now. So what do you think the author should say instead? They cannot say that "the derivatie is continuous", and they want to express the fact that the derivative is continuous on some intervals. How else can they say it besides "piecewise continuous"?

Comment: I would want him to say continuous with piecewise continuous derivative instead of piecewise continuous with piecewise continuous derivative because there exist no examples of the latter where $f$ has actual discontinuities. What do you think?

Comment: @Hmm I have to think about it more but I have to go now. Will check back tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the author means something like $$f(x)=\cases{x,&$0<x<1$\\2x,&$1\leq x<2$}$$  This function is discontinuous at $x=1$, so not differentiable at that point.  A derivative has no jump discontinuities, so when the author talks of a piecewise continuous derivative, he doesn't mean that the derivative exists everywhere.

Comment: and indeed this function is continuous, which sort of proves my point, but can you think of an example in which f is not continuous at least at one point? I think it's impossible.

Comment: @Dalamar No, it's not continuous. (He even told you _where_ it's discontinuous! Did you read what he wrote?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I edited the post after Dalamar's comment.  Originally I had just posted the definition.

Comment: Apologies, I had misread. I still feel that it is not a very well-formulated assumption because, on the surface, the discontinuities in the derivative and the original function seem to be of the same type, but on a closer look, in the case of the derivative, it actually means that at some points it's not defined. Do you share my grievance, at least in part? @saulspatz

Comment: @Dalamar I see what you are saying, certainly.  However, not all authors require that a piecewise continuous function have only jump discontinuities.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiecewiseContinuous.html  If your author has imposed this requirement, then I'd say he's made a technical error, though I understand what he intends.

Comment: @saulspatz I see. Do you think this broader definition of piecewise continuity would be technically more defensible? In his defense the context is Fourier series, which usually do require that there be only at most finite types of discomtinuities, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Dalamar I don't think one is any better the other.  Like a lot of definitions, it depends on what's more convenient in a particular context.  I think you're right about Fourier series, though I don't really remember.